# rails secret token internal server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production

I deployed my rails app in production mode but cant figure out how to solve this error that comes up on localhost. what does this mean?

Internal Server Error 
Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.5/2014-11-13) at localhost:3000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to config/secrets.yml:

```
production:
  secret_token: 7900b0bfb515193f700e0cff69741724bd0cd03d89c49f6462b66d9435d5436bfa27c579bfce5557be1490f89a526c674324f101b858c8c92056c9a92d4fe9ae
  secret_key_base: 3459988a83651e0d4ec453f83623a373d2a1a8adc364a5abf81bab650173b8bdb7f2bd728bf8b2fb198c8c0510e86b649e12e3eb452c5b046887af7b0c794ba0
```

Secrets generate with:

```
rake secret
```